# Adding new columns to Pandas Data Frame which the length of new column value is bigger than length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm in a trouble with adding a new column to a pandas dataframe when the length of  new column value is bigger than length of index.

Data may like this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "bar": ["A","B","C"],
        "zoo": [1,2,3],
                  })
```

So, you see, length of this `df`'s index is 3.

And next I wanna add a new column , code may like this two ways below:

```
df["new_col"] = [1,2,3,4]
```

It'll raise an error : `Length of values does not match length of index`.

Or:

```
df["new_col"] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
```

I will just get values`[1,2,3]` in my data frame `df`.

(The count of new column values can't out of the max index).

Now, what I want just like :

[image]

Is there a better way ?

Looking forward to your answer,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with change Series name and right join:

```
#if not default index
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).rename('new_col'), how='right')
print (df)
   bar  zoo  new_col
0    A  1.0        1
1    B  2.0        2
2    C  3.0        3
3  NaN  NaN        4
```

Another idea is add `reindex` by new `s.index`:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])

df = df.reindex(s.index)
df["new_col"] = s
print (df)
   bar  zoo  new_col
0    A  1.0        1
1    B  2.0        2
2    C  3.0        3
3  NaN  NaN        4
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
df = df.reindex(s.index).assign(new_col = s)
```

Comment: So , what if I wanna add a `Series` when its index bigger than the matched index, just as I posted above .  BTW, I know the method @sygneto head, is there a directly way ?

Comment: I tried , but that not work. I can't get the all values of new `Series`

Comment: @ShinNShirley - sorry, not tested, mea culpa. Added new solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "bar": ["A","B","C"],
        "zoo": [1,2,3],
                  })
new_col = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
df = pd.concat([df,new_col],axis=1)
print(df)
   bar  zoo  0
0    A  1.0  1
1    B  2.0  2
2    C  3.0  3
3  NaN  NaN  4
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Comment: @BDL I got this way and know how it works though, thanks fou your head . I just look for another direct way to solve it  (: